# using VW7.8/Jun789 JunFileDialog for file save and want to remember selected directory for next time

Tags: savefiledialog, visualworks

I am using VW7.8/Jun789 JunFileDialog for a file save as and want to remember/set the selected directory for next time. I am following JunFileDialog class example5. I suppose doing so in the onAccept: block should be possible, but so far I've had no success.

I'm having trouble understanding where or how to set the initialDirectory other than as per the example in the JunFileDialog>>request: messageString initialDirectory: directoryFilename initialFile: filenameString fileTypeMenu: aMenu initialFileType: fileType onAccept: acceptBlock onCancel: cancelBlock.

Is there a better file save dialog to use?

Answer (score 0):

you can use VisualWorks' Dialog class. On class side it has the "file name dialogs" protocol. There you can find methods like #requestFileName:default: or #requestNewFileName:default:. Both should display a native dialog on Windows and Mac OS X which defaults to the last opened folder.

Comment: Answering my own question, I eventually solved the problem by creating an instance variable in which I saved the needed info for next use. I did not find any suitable built in way.